# Error when running vbs via C# application

Tags: c#, vbscript

I want my C# application to run an external vbscript. This Vbs is performing some actions, and needs to retrieve a data from the registry.

The vbscript is launched, but I've got an error : Unable to open registry value for reading.

I don't really understand why.

That's how I run the vbscript :

```
            Process scriptProc = new Process();
            scriptProc.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\windows\system32\wscript";
            scriptProc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = repository + p + "\\"; <-- location of my script : C:\temp\soft\
            scriptProc.StartInfo.Arguments = "MyScript.vbs";
            scriptProc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            scriptProc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
            scriptProc.Start();
            scriptProc.WaitForExit();
            scriptProc.Close();
```

And in my VBS, I read the value like that :

```
strValue = objShell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyKey\MySubKey\MyReg_Sz_Entry")
```

Where "MyReg_Sz_Entry" contains a string value. This value is correctly returned when i run the vbs normally, but not with my C# code.

My account has administrative privilege.

I need some help :).

Thank's

Comment: Why are you doint this at all, instead of reading the registry from C#?

Comment: In any case the error is returned by the script, not C#. Perhaps you are running the script under an account that *doesn't* have permission to read the registry?

Comment: You probably just need to run your c# application as administrator, or add some permission attributes to it.

Comment: Thank's for answers. The way i'm need it, it's because the script install some applications. Everything related to that installation need to be performed inside the script.
You're maybe right, but i don't understand, I'm using the same account. I already have tried by runing my app "as admin"

Comment: @Neandril Change your vbs script to echo the registry key to make sure it is the correct one you are looking at. e.g.

strKey = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\Git CMD\FaceName"
WScript.echo(strKey)
strValue = objShell.RegRead(strKey)

Comment: @HassanVoyeau I already try this, and it is the correct key that i'm looking for. :(

Comment: Maybe vbscript in app and vbscript standalone are seeing different parts of the registry. Read here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sysinfo/32-bit-and-64-bit-application-data-in-the-registry and here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/WmiSdk/requesting-wmi-data-on-a-64-bit-platform

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what were wrong...

That's finally simple : the target architecture of my build.

I changed it in Visual Studio options of my project from "any CPU" to "64 bits", and it's OK now.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: So my comment helped you?

Comment: Your comments oriented me :) I upvoted your comments. But unfortunally, your great solution didn't apply to my case. But it may be usefull for other persons.

Comment: Thanks. Glad I could help.